# What does Greetings! do in Breath of Fire: Dragon Quarter?

Tags: breath-of-fire-dragon-quarter

Lin has a skill called Greetings!, with a description that states:

Greetings - Shot Attack with an Attack Power of 75% - Feint Attack

What does it do on it's own? What does "feint" mean in this context? There's a shield skill also called feint that lets you block an attack once per battle, but I don't see how that would apply here.

Does it have any advantage over something like Hey Hey! as a single shot, or is it purely intended to be used in only two combos, both of which steal items?

Comment: Wow, it's been forever since I played this.  I believe Feint attacks focus the enemy on that character, but I'm no longer 100% on that.

Comment: Well, that's worth testing at least!